# My laptop doesn't always boot to login

Tags: 10.10, boot

I have an recurring problem. Every once in a while, no pattern, the laptop freezes during boot. Sometimes at a black screen, sometimes a black screen with a not blinking cursor...

The solution is to power down the laptop, cross my fingers and boot again. Sometimes it takes four or five reboots, but in the end I always get the system up and running.

What bugs me is the fact that the boot is not 'stable' in a sense that apparently it doesn't always do exactly the same thing.

I'm still using 10.10. The question is whether there is anything that can be done to make the system stable. (Does 11.04 have the same issue?)

**Edit:** Today the same thing happened. First a black screen with a non blinking cursor. Second a black screen. Third login screen.

Comment: When you say "freeze", do you mean "black screen" or "pressing the Caps Lock key does not toggle the Caps Lock light"?

Comment: Freeze as in not starting up and no response to keyboard or mouse. But on pressing the power button, it powers down (I guess that's still the laptop)

Comment: do you just get a black screen? Can you see your cursor (even if you cannot move it?)

Comment: I see what you mean, I'm editing the question.

Comment: You have mentioned in a comment to the accepted answer that you have moved on to 11.04. If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @GUIJunkie - please post the answer that you have move to 11.04 and that this has been resolved by this move.  Please also accept your own answer to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving to 11.04 solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try and look at the logs. It's not very exciting, especially since you often don't know what to look for. The following ones are likely to provide clues:

```
/var/log/dmesg
/var/log/dmesg.0
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

If you find system logs too cryptic, post them to http://www.pastebin.com/ so that other may have a look.

Comment: I'll take a look at that when I can.

Comment: I've gone forwards to 11.04 and so far so good (but ever so slow).

Answer (score 0):

radeon graphic card, i guess? :) install kernel 3.0.0. That's what fixes radeon bug freezing at black/blank screen. Before the kernel upgrade my best record was 15 reboots in a row before it could sign in properly :)

3.0.0 is release candidate, though, so you might (for some unknown reason) not want to use it, downgrade to 2.6.35 then, it didn't have the bug.

Comment: How do I check for the graphic card?

Comment: In the Xorg.0.log file there is a "(II) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) 915GM"

Comment: This is a 2005 Laptop. Maybe I should be looking for a new one :)